# Code validation in W3C validator getting failed due to aria-required attribute

Tags: javascript, css, html, w3c-validation

I have a simple login page in my application with username and password fields.
My application is developed by JAVA and it uses Primefaces UI framework.

I have added a Primefaces inputText (p:inputText) for username field and Primefaces password (p:password) for password field.

After the page has rendered in browser, the code probably seems like below.

```
<div class="text">
   <label for="email">E-mail: </label> 
   <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="20" aria-required="true" /> *
</div>
<div class="text">
   <label id="passwordCtrl" for="last">Password: </label> 
   <input type="password" id="passwordCtrl" name="password" size="20" aria-required="true" /> *
</div>
```

When I try to validate the HTML code in https://validator.w3.org/, it showing validation error message as shown below.

[image: W3C validator message screen]

To get the code to validate, right click on the page and select View Source, then copy the entire code and paste the code in W3C validator.

Among the two controls, the issue is only with the `input[type="password"]` control. How to handle this HTML code validation error? Is there any way to achieve this?

Note: 
I am using Primefaces UI framework

Comment: There's a page on the w3c website that explains how to add that attribute with Javascript...   https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA2.html

Comment: Please see the latest update in the question.

Comment: The checker is reporting that “Attribute aria-required not allowed on element input at this point” message because per the requirements in the ARIA in HTML spec for using ARIA attributes with <input type=password…>, it’s not allowed to have any role and it is only allowed to have the ARIA global attributes.

The aria-required attribute is not one of the ARIA global attributes. In HTML the aria-required attribute is only allowed when an element has a particular role value such as role=searchbox or role=textbox or for elements which have an implicit role that allows.